# Nifi JoltTransformJSON : Keeping the underscore sign in key name

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to write a jolt in Apache Nifi that converts the json form. I managed to convert the jolt but one attribute is missing underscore:

Output:

```
          {
     "Source": {   //source is missing underscore. It should look like _Source
           "userName": "Lulu"
      }
  }
```

My input is as following:

```
     {
        "user_name": "Lulu"
     }
```

Currently my jolt expression looks like following:

```
[
        {
          "operation": "shift",
          "spec": {
               "user_name":"userName"
           }
        },
        {
          "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
          "spec": {         
              "_Source":{
                  "userName":"@(2,userName)"
               }
           }
         },
         { "operation": "remove", 
          "spec": { 

                    "userName": "" } 
               }
]
```

How do I keep the underscore sign in attribute "Source"?

I am stuck at figuring out this part. I'm wondering what am I missing in the jolt expression. Thanks in advance, guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the underscore might be some kind of special character in that operator, try double-backslashes in front of _Source:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user_name": "userName"
    }
        },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "\\_Source": {
        "userName": "@(2,userName)"
      }
    }
         },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "userName": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do it just with a single "shift".

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user_name": "_Source.userName"
    }
  }
]
```